# Reading XML file from Client machine - getting - Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm currently trying to READ XML file from the client machine where the user can open from any location (there is no specific location). However, i browse to the folder and select the xml file and when it execute this line (below) it throw an error complaining about access to the path is denied any idea how should i approach?

error: **System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is Denied**

```
Dim reader As New XmlTextReader(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(File1.PostedFile.FileName)) 

            Dim m_xmlr As XmlTextReader
            'Create the XML Reader
            m_xmlr = New XmlTextReader(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(File1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()))
            'Disable whitespace so that you don't have to read over whitespaces
            m_xmlr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
            'read the xml declaration and advance to family tag
            m_xmlr.Read()   **<<<<<ERROR**
            'read the family tag
            m_xmlr.Read()
            'Load the Loop
            While Not m_xmlr.EOF
                 ..............
                 .............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running on the server. You can't just read from the client's local drive like that. You should use the [`InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) of the file to get the data. For example:

```
Dim m_xmlr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(File1.PostedFile.InputStream)
```